# Requirement for setting JRE path in windows7, like setting path for JDK

Tags: windows-7, path, java

Should I have to add/set the path for JRE as well like I did for JDK 1.7? If yes, then please explain how. If no then why it is not necessary. (I am using windows 7, 64 bit)

Thank you.

Comment: I thought setting up `JAVA_HOME` was sufficient enough. No?

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman Should I have to add JAVA_HOME?? I add the Jdk path  (e.g: c:/program files/java/....) is it OK?

Comment: Most java programs searches `JAVA_HOME` to identify where the JDK and JRE are found. Your `JAVA_HOME` must point to the java directory (where `bin`, `jre`, `lib` folder sits).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "JDK" is the Java Development Kit. I.e., the JDK is bundle of software that you can use to develop Java based software.

The "JRE" is the Java Runtime Environment. I.e., the JRE is an implementation of the Java Virtual Machine which actually executes Java programs. Without JRE one can only compile the application but cannot run the application.

Since JRE contains the JVM which executes the byte code generated from the javac compiler, you need to add your JRE path to JAVA_HOME variable from the environment variables. Here's the tutorial for doing so: http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. But now in my java folder there are two jre 6 and jre 7 folder in my java folder. (c:/program files/java/). which to choose?

Comment: Then I recommend you to use the JRE 7 inside of your JDK folder.

Comment: @AbdulAziz : No point in keeping the two versions of java on the same machine, it always leads to clash or conflict. Better remove the previous version, and then do what you want to do.  :-)  Regards

Comment: It mean that I have to add Jre path as well? (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\jre\bin) in path?

Comment: In fact, if you set your JDK in your JAVA_HOME variable and use '%JAVA_HOME%\bin' in your PATH variable as @pnt mentions, you don't need to add JRE path. But adding the JRE path is nothing but a guaranted way of doing things, so yes you should also add JRE path as well.

Comment: @AbdulAziz you're welcome. I hope I managed to answer your question.

Comment: @KorhanÖztürk Yes I actually took your advice and did what you told. But I didn't check it that its working or not. Because I am reading a very cool book for Java development, so in its beginning I have some difficulty so as the problems coming, I am asking.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the JDK contains the JRE, so if you have set your PATH properly you shouldn't need a separate entry for the JRE.

Think of it this way - the JRE contains everything you need to run a Java program. The JDK contains everything you need to run AND develop the program.

Comment: Its mean that installing Jdk and setting its path in enough? Setting path for Jre additionally is required?